# socket.io message still broadcasted even though client has left the room

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I've put together a chat application where people can join/leave rooms. I have come across something very strange and I really can't get my head around it.

This is an excerpt from my server.js (backend):

```
client.on("send", function(msg) {
  console.log("Sending to ==> " + client.room);
  if ('undefined' !== typeof client.room) {
    socket.sockets.in(client.room).emit("chat", people[client.id], msg);
  }
});
```

I'm essentially 'forcing' people to join a room (if they are not in a room, client.room returns undefined.)

I have placed two buttons on the frontend, one to join a room and one to leave a room. The join button is handled via:

```
client.on("joinRoom", function(name) {
  client.join(name); //where name is the name of the room coming from the frontend
 }
```

The leave room function looks like this:

```
client.on("leaveRoom", function(name) {
  client.leave(name);
}
```

Now, the problem is this: after the client.leave(name); bit, the user can still send a message, and console.log("Sending to ==> " + client.room); will still output 'Sending to ==> room1') whereas the client has left the room. I confirmed this with "socket.sockets.clients(client.room)" - the client is not listed here anymore.

Does anyone have any idea why I still emit message from a client to a room that his not part of?

**UPDATE**

After the answer from DRC, I have updated my send function:

```
client.on("send", function(msg) {
  for (key in socket.sockets.manager.roomClients[client.id]) {
    if (key ==="/" + client.room) {
      socket.sockets.in(client.room).emit("chat", people[client.id], msg);  
    }
  }
});
```

Is this the most elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning client.room , and not deleting it whenever the client leaves the room, socket.io is not checking about authorizations for that, you must.

So do a delete client.room whenever the client leaves the room or check if the user is in a room checking the content of `io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]` , see the [docs](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms)

**UPDATE**
*after op question mod.*

you already have the room name, so the key for roomClients[socket.id], you could check:

```
if (socket.sockets.manager.roomClients[client.id]['/'+client.room] !== undefined ){
    //the user is part of this room
}
```

but yes that is the logic.